# How to set up manually the next value of auto_increment?

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I added some rows into the table manually and also I set up the ID (auto_increment) manually. Now when I try to add new row through my app into DB table, to DB table I am getting the error , that the created ID value already exist.

How can I set manually the next ID value (for example, in table I have to IDs, so how to tell to PostgreSQL, that the next ID should be counted since the number 3)?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

```
select setval('sequence-name', <new-value>);
```

You can get the sequence name from the the table definition:

```
id       | integer                | not null default nextval('id_seq'::regclass)
```

In this case the sequence is named 'id_seq'

Edit (10x to @Glenn):

```
SELECT setval('id_seq', max(id)) FROM table;
```

Comment: And set <new-value> to the result of SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM myTable.

Comment: As per documentation setval given two parameters sets the given sequence value to given number max(id) which technically sets the nextval to max(id)+1. In other words you should not use max(id)+1 unless you want to skip the max(id)+1 number, or use false as third parameter.

Answer (score 13):

I think there is a simpler way:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE "seq_product_id"  RESTART WITH 10
```