# Postgres INSERT INTO autoincrement table with single column primary key

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, primary-key

I am trying to auto increment a table with a single column which is a primary key, eg:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (id PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

I would usually just not include the primary key column in the insert statment in order to autoincrement it, but this doesn't seem possible in the case where there is only a single column. The below results in `"syntax error at or near \")\""`

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table () VALUES ();
```

Comment: May we ask why you would ever need to do this?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114779/how-to-set-up-manually-the-next-value-of-auto-increment

Comment: Another option `create table my_table (id serial primary key);` Then as @Belayer shows in his answer, `insert into my_table (id) values (default);`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the this the table is orders for an online shop and *all* the other information related to the order is many to one, eg there are many products per order, many events per order, etc, so all the data for each order is stored in other tables.
I will probably add more columns to the table in the future, but I don't find it that hard to think of other use cases that will have the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

Define your column as an identity then on insert specify the keyword DEFAULT.

```
create table dumb_id ( id   integer  generated always as identity primary key); 
insert into dumb_id (id) values (default);
```

Note: You do not use quotes around default.  [Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BQdlpM5P)  
But what is the point of such a table?

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of id = Auto Value when insert
Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (id Serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO my_table(id) VALUES( nextval('my_table_id_seq'::regclass));
```

Comment: Tried this and got the following error: `relation \"my_table_id_seq\" does not exist`

Comment: It is Sequences Name of ID, You must add "Serial" in sql "CREATE TABLE my_table (id Serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);"

Comment: You can also replace it with "default" the same other comment.